# Location issues in solving OD Cost Matrix ArcGIS 10.6.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.6

I created a network dataset only for cars from my overall street network. 
I am getting a partial solve for The two warning messages I keep getting are `Warning: Location "0935010000038273" in "Origins" does not have a corresponding network element. The network dataset needs to be rebuilt.`

and also that there is `no destination for location "x."` I have 61814 point origin locations (all of which display as located, no errors) and 1 point destination. The OD cost matrix solves for 53213 locations out of the 61814. There are no barriers applied, and the only restriction I have is the Oneway restriction automatically generated by the Network Dataset wizard.

The parameters I used for adding the origin and destination locations was to use the network location information for each location, and I set all point location data to snap to the network with a 5m offset.

Is this an issue with the network dataset restriction or the network dataset itself? Or is it an issue I did not have the error message about corresponding network elements for using the same network (but selected for cyclists, and no one-way restriction). I previously ran an OD cost matrix for cycling that solved for majority of locations, but had also the "no destination for location x" warning.